# Flutter i trying to crop/resize image into 1:1 ratio but i got a problem when i use image_cropper package

Tags: flutter, dart, package, image-cropper

im trying to crop an image that i retrieve from gallery or take a photo and i need to resize the image into 1:1 size and upload it to firebase

this is the code that i already try but i got some error

```
 Future<Null> _cropImage(File image) async {
    File? croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: image.path,
        maxWidth: 1080,
        maxHeight: 1080,
        aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1.0, ratioY: 1.0)
    );
    if (croppedImage  != null) {
        imageFile = croppedImage ;
        setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

this is the code that i use to get image and crop the image

down below is my original code that i used to take image without no problem

```
Future _getCameraImage() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.camera,
        imageQuality: 40,
        maxHeight: 800,
        maxWidth: 800);

    setState(() {
      _image = File(image!.path);
    });
  }
```

and this is the error i got from flutter

and when i put the _getCameraImage in my TextButton.icon onpressed like this. they didt gave me anything

```
TextButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () => _getCameraImage,
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                            label: const Text('Camera'),
                          ),
```

i want to get image from camera and display it on my imageview

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think image cropper library's read me file is not updated properly or it was an mistake from their end, thats why they show `ImageCropper.cropImage` instead of `ImageCropper().cropImage`.

As per image cropper library example, you have to create the image cropper object first to use the cropping mechanism because `cropImage` is not an static method.

So try to use `ImageCropper().cropImage`

```
 Future<Null> _cropImage(File image) async {
    File? croppedImage = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
        sourcePath: image.path,
        maxWidth: 1080,
        maxHeight: 1080,
        aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1.0, ratioY: 1.0)
    );
    if (croppedImage  != null) {
        imageFile = croppedImage ;
        setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

Comment: uhm once more question, how can i put them inTextbutton onPressed. they show this error when i put it `The argument type 'Future<Null> Function(File)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.`

Comment: @BillyStanly share your full code so that we can understand.

Comment: i will update my code. well when i click the button it didnt show me anything

Comment: Please post your all the codes like button click codes not just the image pick and image crop function so that we can atleast check/run this code our own machine and get the actual error to understand what happend.

Comment: done. updated it already

Comment: Try to use void return type void or Future<void> _cropImage() and  _getCameraImage().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243358/discussion-between-billy-stanly-and-zakaria-hossain).